# is there a fast implementation of the log1p function?

Tags: java, math

I want to have a fast log1p function for Java. Java has Math.log1p, but it is apparently too slow for my needs.

I have found this code for log1p here:

http://golang.org/src/pkg/math/log1p.go

for the GO language.

Is it the same like the one in Java, or is it a faster one? (assuming I translate it to java).
Anyone is aware of some other fast implementation of log1p?

Thanks.

Comment: There are a couple of good short ones, implemented in terms of log, in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24134816/goldbergs-log1p-vs-gsl-log1p

Answer (score -3, accepted):

since `log1p(x) = Math.log(x+1)`, finding a natural log fast algorithm is sufficient for what you need.

> Fast Natural Logarithm in Java
>
> I have found the following approximation here, and there is not much
>   information about it except that it is called “Borchardt’s Algorithm”
>   and it is from the book “Dead Reconing: Calculating without
>   instruments”. The approximation is not very good (some might say very
>   bad…), it gets worse the larger the values are. But the approximation
>   is also a monotonic, slowly increasing function, which is good enough
>   for my use case.
>
> public static double log(double x) {
>       return 6 * (x - 1) / (x + 1 + 4 * (Math.sqrt(x))); }
>
> This approximation is 11.7 times faster than Math.log().

See [this](http://martin.ankerl.com/2007/02/11/optimized-exponential-functions-for-java/) site. Also, [a performance comparison for math libraries in java.](http://blog.juma.me.uk/2011/02/23/performance-of-fastmath-from-commons-math/)

But probably what you **need** is to link to c++ compiled stuff, detailed [here](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javatips/jw-javatip141.html).

Comment: You are missing the point of `log1p`.  When x is very small (e.g. 1e-20), `x+1.0` is rounded to `1.0` because of the limited precision of a `double`, and `log(1.0)` returns a (wrong) result of `0`.  You may think "well this is close enough to 0" but what if the next step is to multiply the result by a very large number?

Comment: when x is very small, then log(x+1) ~ x (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm#Derivative.2C_Taylor_series ), that could be handled by an if statement if the value of x is smaller than a certain threshold.

Comment: @AndreHolzner: it could be handled that way, but not very well. A quality implementation would be accurate to within a few low-order bits no matter what the input.  With your approach, depending on what threshold you choose, you'll get poor results either just below the threshold, or just above the threshold, or both.

Answer (score 0):

In "What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic" (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) there is a short algorithm to compute `log1p` within 5 epsilon for `0<=x<3/4` and given certain requirements on the arithmetic

```
double xp1 = 1+x;
if(xp1==1)
   return x;
else
   return x * log(xp1) / (xp1-1);
```

Maybe this performs better on your system than the builtin `log1p` implementation. However, use it with care (see the paper for things that could go wrong e.g. in extended-base systems) and have some tests ready.