Unexpected behaviour of log1p numpy
I am using the function numpy.log1p to calculate the value of log(1 + x) for very small complex numbers, and I am getting unexpected results.
I would expect that outputs should be practically equal to the function input. While this does not seem to be the case in the simple examples below.
np.log1p(1e-14 * (1 + 1j))
Out[75]: (9.992007221626358e-15+9.9999999999999e-15j)
np.log1p(1e-15 * (1 + 1j))
Out[76]: (1.110223024625156e-15+9.999999999999989e-16j)
np.log1p(1e-16 * (1 + 1j))
Out[77]: 1e-16j

The log1p function from scipy.special seems to be working correctly, but unfortunatelly I need to use the numpy function (for numba).
I am currently using numpy version 1.26.4 on Python 3.10.10
np.__version__
Out[78]: '1.26.4'

Update
As pointed out in the answer below, Numpy seems to have a fairly lazy implementation of log1p for complex numbers. However I belive I found a way to fix it:
def log1p_corrected(x):
    """Precise calculation of log(1 + x) in the complex case"""
    re_x = np.real(x)
    im_x = np.imag(x)

    # |1 + x|**2 - 1
    norm2_min_1 = 2 * re_x + re_x**2 + im_x**2

    # real part of log(1+x)
    re_log1p = np.log1p(norm2_min_1) / 2

    # imaginary part of log(1+x)
    im_log1p = np.arctan2(im_x, 1 + re_x)

    return re_log1p + 1j * im_log1p

The main difference with numpy implementation consist in the evaluation of the real part of the logarithm (log|1 + x|). I simply rewrote the formula to use np.log1p, which works properly for real numbers.
I would like to point out that alternative implementations which rely on series exapansions are viable, fast and perform extremely well for very small x. However, I would like to avoid introducing (small) discontinuities in the function due to using different methods based on the values of |x|.

log(1+x) is approximately equal to x for small x ... and that appears to be exactly what you are getting. Which one do you think is wrong? 9.99e-15 is very nearly 1e-14 etc.

The imaginary part of the results matches well, but not the real part

The numpy docs say:

For real-valued input, log1p is accurate also for x so small that 1 + x == 1 in floating-point accuracy.

Which seems to be an indirect way of saying they "gave up" on complex inputs. Indeed, in plain Python (which doesn't have cmath.log1p), on Windows:
>>> import cmath
>>> p = 1e-14 * (1 + 1j)
>>> p
(1e-14+1e-14j)
>>> cmath.log(1 + p)
(9.992007221626409e-15+9.9999999999999e-15j)

which is very close to what you got. So sure looks like numpy.log1p(c) for complex c is adding 1.0 to c before calling numpy.log().
The result "should be" close to p - p**2/2 for p so small (just the first two terms of the Taylor expansion of log(1+p) around p=0):
>>> p - p**2/2
(1e-14+9.9999999999999e-15j)

which is essentially delivered by the mpmath extension module:
>>> import mpmath
>>> p = mpmath.mpc(1, 1) * 1e-14
>>> p
mpc(real='1.0e-14', imag='1.0e-14')
>>> mpmath.log1p(p)
mpc(real='1.0e-14', imag='9.9999999999999006e-15')

So this looks like a (inadequately documented) limitation of numpy's current implementation of log1p().
So if you have to use numpy for this, you'll have to supply your own alternative.
What numpy does
Under the covers, numpy.log1p(c) converts c+1 to polar form and then uses:
log(r * e**(j*t)) = log(r) + j*t

to build the result. So if c = a + b*j, the result has

real part: log(hypot(a + 1, b))
imag part: atan2(b, a + 1)

If |a| is so small that a + 1 loses some (or all!) information to rounding, tough luck.
A caution about accuracy
Consider complex c = -5.884298465609164e-91 + 1.0848313692199447e-45j.
That was generated "at random" during testing. Unfortunately, no approach on the table does a good job on it, short of setting mpmath to use a few hundred bits of precision.
Why: let R be the real part and J be the imaginary part. The real part of log1p(c) is log(hypot(R+1, J)). Behold! ;-)
>>> import mpmath
>>> from mpmath import log, hypot, mpf, workprec. mpc
>>> R = -5.884298465609164e-91
>>> J = 1.0848313692199447e-45
>>> hypot(R+1, J)
mpf('1.0')
>>> with workprec(400):
...     hypot(R+1, J)
mpf('1.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005884295498218099788929146684839')

Because it goes on to take the log of that, those give very different outcomes.
This is because hypot(1+R. J) is in turn sqrt((1 + R)^^2 + J**2) = sqrt(1 + R**2 + 2*R + J**2) and it doesn't actually help us to know that log(sqrt(1+f)) is approximately f/2 when f is very small.
Forget R**2 because it's exceedingly tiny in this case. It's the 2*R + J**2 that hurts us:
>>> 2*R
-1.1768596931218329e-90
>>> J**2
1.17685909964362e-90
>>> 2*R + J**2
-5.934782129408062e-97

2*R and J**2 are so close to each other's negations that close to the 7 most significant decimal digits cancel out when we add them. With extra precision, those bits are replaced by the leading bits of the part of J**2 that was lost to rounding:
>>> with workprec(200):
...     2*mpf(R) + mpf(J)**2
mpf('-5.9347821292576139709922469679882199756565314433969258094957309e-97')

That only matches the 53-bit result in the first 10 digits. Without extra precision, the trailing bits of J**2 are just plain lost forever.
>>> c = mpc(R, J)
>>> with workprec(400): # as good as it gets
...     mpmath.log1p(c)
mpc(real='-2.9673910646288069854961234839941099878282657216984629047478654331954101753008213969808976137411482956635728432029405164533e-97', imag='1.0848313692199446892733858946092178721423949541818749887436188379566165369930349882511849209687548440293467928718096798443e-45')

>>> mpmath.log1p(c) # last 4+ digits are trash
mpc(real='-2.9673910646284523e-97', imag='1.0848313692199447e-45')

>>> mpmath.log(c + 1) # total trash
mpc(real='5.8842954982180997e-91', imag='1.0848313692199447e-45')

>>> c2 = c + 1 # this trick is a little worse than plain log1p
>>> c * mpmath.log(c2) / (c2 - 1)
mpc(real='-2.9673910647040311e-97', imag='1.0848313692199447e-45')

>>> xxtest(c) #  # 4-term Taylor series the same
mpc(real='-2.9673910647040311e-97', imag='1.0848313692199447e-45')

This is harder to worm around than the 1-dimensional (real-valued log1p) case: it's "deep" more than "shallow", because the catastrophic cancellation occurs not in what we're computing, but under the covers in the bowels of the implementation. It's not enough to use tricks that preserve the full precision of R despite adding 1 to R, because that's not where the problem is in this case: it's instead that we don't retain enough precision of J**2 to compensate for the possibility that its leading bits may be lost to cancellation when adding 2*R to it. But even getting at those trailing J**2 bits requires some way of getting the effect of using extra precision.
Follow-ups
I have yet to see a reliable log1p(complex) implementation, short of  running mpmath with absurdly (in context) high precision.
Part of this appears to be a bug in mpmath.log1p(). I found a case where every bit of the real part of the result was wrong. So opened a  bug report. This appears to be a case where part of the implementation temporarily boosts the precision by a little, to absorb rounding errors, not realizing that this increase will convince a later part of the implementation to take a wrong branch. Specifically, this case would have been fine if it had used the 2-term Taylor series expansion, but it mistakenly believes that precision is large enough that it's fine to do log(c+1) in doubled precision instead. But it isn't. Not even tripled precision would be enough.
So, until that's fixed, it's possible that mpmath precision has to be forced to a few thousand bits to cover all cases.
Relatedly, I wrote my own lop1p(complex) in Python. It's the only reliable one I know of ;-) I used to write commercial math libraries as parts of my day jobs, so I have high standards for "reliable". In particular, I don't much care about relative error in norms. Instead my view is that there is a infinitely precise correct result, and the stringent measure of error is how many ULPs (units in the last place) the real and imaginary parts are removed from that ideal. This is unforgiving.
Even in "ordinary" cases the other implementations I've seen routinely deliver results that differ by 50 ULP from ideal (summing the absolute ULP errors in the real and imaginary parts).
The implementation I have now has never reached 3 ULP total error, across over 200 million randomized test cases so far, This is the worst result to date:
new max 2.894273405102144 at (0.0019532098478106533-5.356595846417641e-17j)
   (0.0019513048136734744  -5.3461536863894766e-17j) got
   (0.0019513048136734748  -5.346153686389476e-17j)  ideal

So it's "at worst small difference in the last displayed digits" territory. Achieving this was entirely a matter of controlling error propagation in the real part, and required emulating extra precision. I believe doing better than this would require replacing the platform real-valued atan2(), log(), and log1p() functions with always-correctly-rounded ones.

Thanks for your answer! I will fix the issue via the series expansion you mentioned. The numpy documentation is really cryptic though

Just be sure to use a series only when appropriate ;-) This kind of series for log(1+p) doesn't even converge (with an infinite number of terms) if abs(p) > 1. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1356517/what-is-the-correct-radius-of-convergence-for-ln1x  Although the "just two terms" gives a very good approximation for |p| as small as you've shown.

Will do, thanks. I was already planning to use the series only within a small radius around the origin.

The next term in the series is + p**3/3. So after computing p - p**2/2, if adding p**3/3 leaves the result unchanged in floating-point, you can be sure you're very close to the best possible result already.

See new edit at the end of my post for a depressing ;-) note about accuracy.

@TimPeters so when is log1p going to be added to Python's cmath module?

@asmeurer, my guess is never. I went on to contribute an efficient, high-accuracy implementation to mpmath, but that relies on internal mpmath facilities that don't exist at all in CPython I have less than no interest in porting all that. log1p() for complex numbers is a dubious idea to begin with.

I would suggest using either a three or four term Taylor series here. You're using Numba, so it's pretty straightforward to get something that's both accurate and perfomant.
Here is how you can implement this:
import numba as nb


@nb.vectorize(fastmath=True)
def log1p_acc(x):
    if np.abs(x) >= 1e-3:
        # np.log1p is accurate for large values of x
        return np.log1p(x)
    else:
        terms = 4
        x_pow = x
        sign = 1
        sum_ = 0
        for i in range(1, terms + 1):
            # Note: use * (1 / i) to allow optimizer to avoid fdiv
            sum_ += sign * x_pow * (1 / i)
            sign *= -1
            x_pow *= x
        return sum_

To change the number of terms, you can change the terms variable.
Accuracy
Let's measure how accurate this function is.
First, in order to quantify how accurate our replacement is, we need three things: a reference implementation, a test data set, and an error metric.
I chose the mpmath.log1p implementation as my reference implementation, and set the accuracy to 1000 digits.1
Next, we need to ask what domain we care about accuracy across. I assumed that you only care about small numbers, so I generated samples from a log-uniform distribution spanning from 1e-30 to 1. This essentially assumes that you care about the range from 1e-30 to 1e-29 as much as you care about the range 0.1 to 1. Here is an example of what a log uniform distribution looks like when plotted as a histogram, with linear and log scales. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_distribution#/media/File:Reciprocal_Histogram.svg
Using that log-uniform distribution, I sampled from one of four cases an equal number of times:

Real and complex are independent log uniform samples.
Real and complex are the same log uniform sample.
Real is log uniform, and complex is zero.
Real is zero, and complex is log uniform.

This forms my test set for evaluating performance.
Third, I chose an error metric. By some metrics, your result with np.log1p isn't so bad: it differs from the true result by about 10-17, which is about the machine epsilon. In relative terms, it's bad - it's about 0.07% off.
For that reason, I think you're more interested in relative error. I measured this using the formula error = abs(true - pred)/abs(true), where abs() is the complex absolute value.
I then compared my function, SciPy's log1p, and NumPy's log1p. The following plot graphs relative error versus absolute value of the input, for three different ways of calculating it.

There are a few notable things about this plot:

For some inputs, NumPy has a relative error of nearly 100%. For example, the code np.log1p((1e-16+1e-30j)) returns a value with zero as the real term.
SciPy is much more accurate than NumPy - most inputs are accurate to about 1e-16.
From x=1e-30 to 1e-4, the custom method has error of less than 1e-16.
At x=1e-4, the error of the custom method rises above SciPy. If it did not switch back to NumPy at x=1e-3, the error would keep rising, especially as you move outside the interval of convergence.

Here's the code used to produce this plot:
import numba as nb
import numpy as np
import scipy.special as sc
import scipy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpmath
mpmath.mp.dps = 1000

plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (12,8)



def generate_log_distribution(N):
    """Generate small numbers spanning many orders of magnitude"""
#     return 10 ** np.random.uniform(-3, -30, size=N)
    return scipy.stats.loguniform.rvs(1e-30, 1e-0, size=N)

test_set_size = 100000 // 4
test_set1 = generate_log_distribution(test_set_size) + 1j * generate_log_distribution(test_set_size)
identical_real_complex = generate_log_distribution(test_set_size)
test_set2 = identical_real_complex + 1j * identical_real_complex
test_set3 = generate_log_distribution(test_set_size) + 0j
test_set4 = 1j * generate_log_distribution(test_set_size) + 0
test_set = np.concatenate([test_set1, test_set2, test_set3, test_set4])
test_set_ref = [mpmath.log1p(c) for c in test_set]


@nb.vectorize(fastmath=True)
def log1p_acc(x):
    if np.abs(x) >= 1e-3:
        # np.log1p is accurate for large values of x
        return np.log1p(x)
    else:
        terms = 4
        x_pow = x
        sign = 1
        sum_ = 0
        for i in range(1, terms + 1):
            # Note: use (1 / i) to allow optimizer to avoid fdiv
            sum_ += sign * x_pow * (1 / i)
            sign *= -1
            x_pow *= x
        return sum_


functions = [
    ("NumPy log1p", np.log1p),
    ("SciPy log1p", sc.log1p),
    ("Custom log1p", log1p_acc),
]
for func_name, func in functions:
    x = []
    y = []
    for i in range(len(test_set)):
        number = test_set[i]
        logged = func(number)
        # Do error calculation in arbitrary precision
        logged = mpmath.mpc(logged)
        out = logged - test_set_ref[i]
        out_abs = mpmath.fabs(out)
        number_abs = mpmath.fabs(number)
        relative_err = out_abs / mpmath.fabs(test_set_ref[i])
        x.append(number_abs)
        y.append(relative_err)
    print(f"Report for {func_name}")
    print(f"Average relative error: {float(np.mean(y))}")
#     print("Worst", np.max(y), "for", test_set[np.argmax(y)])
    print()
    plt.scatter(x, y, label=func_name, s=1, alpha=0.1)
    plt.xscale('log')
    plt.yscale('log')
    plt.xlabel('Norm of x')
    plt.ylabel('Relative error in log1p(x)')
    leg = plt.legend()
    for lh in leg.legend_handles:
        lh.set_alpha(1)
        lh.set_sizes([20])

1 Note that setting dps to 1000 only means that intermediate calculations are done with 1000 digits of accuracy. It does not necessarily mean that the final result is accurate to a thousand digits. It might only be accurate to half that. I have not checked how numerically stable mpmath.log1p() is.
Performance
I compared the performance of this function versus the SciPy and NumPy versions by taking the log1p of the entire test set. It is roughly 2x faster than NumPy, and 3x faster than SciPy. It takes about 14 nanoseconds per log1p evaluation.
Code:
print("NumPy log1p")
%timeit np.log1p(test_set)
print("SciPy log1p")
%timeit sc.log1p(test_set)
print("Custom log1p")
%timeit log1p_acc(test_set)

Output:
NumPy log1p
2.98 ms ± 63.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
SciPy log1p
3.69 ms ± 5.58 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
Custom log1p
1.42 ms ± 2.74 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

I applied the following ideas to make this fast:

I began with the Taylor series, and turned it into a loop. Instead of using exponentiation to calculate each term, I multiplied the previous term by x.
Floating point division is usually slightly slower than floating point multiplication. For that reason, I rewrote sign * x_pow / i as sign * x_pow * (1 / i)
As terms is a constant, Numba is smart enough to fully unroll this loop, which makes this as fast as writing the Taylor series out explicitly.
I used fastmath, which allows Numba to re-arrange the order it does math in.
I found that having a sign variable was slightly faster than selecting either -= or += with the loop index.


Try it without boosting mpmath precision? Telling it to use 1000 digits is much slower than letting it stick to the default (15). Internally. mpmath log1p() uses the 2-term Taylor series if the argument is very small, else computes log(1+p) but with twice the context precision (rounding back at the end). So in most of your test cases, if you leave it alone it will use 106-bit binary fp internally (rwice the default 53 bits). That should be "good enough".
https://github.com/mpmath/mpmath/blob/953acc43d7a282e1187621eb27497d4025591890/mpmath/functions/functions.py#L165

@TimPeters I tried dps=15 prior to posting this, and I got a result which I didn't believe: that the log1p_acc() function had literally 0 error in 77% of cases. Here's what the graph looks like. The missing values are missing because it can't plot 0 values on a log plot. I tried higher precision values of 100 and 1000, and got higher error values that seemed more reasonable. I posted the more pessimistic version.

When you're in the range where mpmath uses the 2-term Taylor series, the argument is so small that the dps setting is irrelevant to the result, and so are the higher-order terms in your fatter Taylor series (only the first two terms make any difference to the final result). So they produce identical results. But the higher you force dps, the smaller the argument has to be to convince mpmath to use its 2-term series. It's only by miracle ;-) that a 1000-digit mpmath result could exactly equal a 15-digit result from your custom function. Not surprising they could often match across 53 bits.

Thanks for the very detailed analysi! I think your function performs well except for the small discontinuity you introduced by setting the 1e-3 threshold. I found also a related question on java where they were suggesting using a neat trick to calculate log1p https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8346218/is-there-a-fast-implementation-of-the-log1p-function. I am investigating a bit the limitations of that approach, but for now it seems to be working well for small values of x.

Note that the 4-term Taylor series has very bad cases too. Fot a dramatic example, argument -1.8389673960970906e-118-1.9177942517888048e-59j. The real part of the result has no correct bits - even the exponent is way off. mpmath's log1p has very bad cases too. See https://github.com/mpmath/mpmath/issues/790 for "deep" analysis of what goes wrong, and code that works. O() analysis of convergence of a complex series ignores the severe numeric problems that can arise due to catastrophic cancellation in finite-precision arithmetic.
